# Unity Mirror Shader double image in HTC Vive / Steam VR

Tags: unity, shaders, virtual-reality, htc-vive, steam-vr

I'm implementing a mirror in Unity for SteamVR / HTC Vive. I'm using [the mirror reflection shader for Unity](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MirrorReflection4). It looks fine, overall, but the left eye and right eye don't align unfortunately, so it's creating double image. How do I resolve it?